# System.ArgumentException: Column 'sku' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

> System.ArgumentException: Column 'sku' does not belong to table . at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)

Am reading a csv file from ftp and storing it in a datatable with that datatable am updating the db Matched columns... this works fine in local...
I'm getting above error when i deploy my webservice in server, but couldnt reproduce in my local. I even tried with the server database backup couldnt reproduce in my local... Any help??

Comment: Without any code or data given, I don't think we can do anything for you. To get a good answer, you need a good question. Maybe you can edit it, so somebody can actually find an answer.

Comment: Check is your table not empty, check is sku column contains in columns and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
string datefrom1 = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString();  
string dateto1 = TestContext.DataRow["Column2"].ToString();
string querydata = TestContext.DataRow["Column3"].ToString();
```

Comment: first column value accessed using column index and later continued with string column name